# paypal check shipping address instead of billing

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, paypal-express

In our shop we have set specific countries for our Paypal Express, fx we don't allow this billing option for Vietnam.
Now we see some customers making orders by setting an American billing address and shipping to Vietnam.

How do we make the system check the shipping address instead of the billing address?